# Entity framework: cannot save context due to the conflict even though record that is causing conflict is also removed from context

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have some code that deletes data from multiple tables and here is a simplified situation:

TableA has a foreign key from tableB and tableC. TableA - tableB connection is set to be cascade on delete. In the code I first remove all tableB records which should, if I am not wrong, automatically remove all tableA records. Then I remove tableC records and try to save context and I get exception with message "the delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint ...".

Is it supposed to work like this or I misunderstood something?

Comment: the full exception text may help us to help you.

Comment: @tschmit007 full exception text is "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_GoalAchievement_Goal\". The conflict occurred in database \"MyDb\", table \"dbo.GoalAchievement\", column 'GoalId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: Also one interesting thing is that I tried this simplified example from my question and it works fine. In my real case (not simplified), there are more tables included. Let's say tableF and tableG and based on cascade rules delete should function like this tableF -> tableG -> tableB -> tableA and that also works fine when I don't try to delete records from tableC in same transaction. As soon as I try to include deletion of records from tableC in same transaction I get that exception.

Comment: what then is the sql defintion of the FK_GoalAchievement_Goal constraint ? (I guess there is a mission ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: @tschmit007 there is nothing for that relationship. On Cascade is set on relationship between GoalAchievement and other table whose records are deleted.